# Using COUNT and inner join in PDO query

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way of writing this SQL statement as a PDO query? I want it to return the number of queries as a number.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    ts_room a
        INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
            ON a.id = b.room_ID
        INNER JOIN ts_request c
            ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1
```

This is what I was thinking:

```
$room_ID = $_POST["room"];

$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    ts_room a
        INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
            ON a.id = b.:room_ID
        INNER JOIN ts_request c
            ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1";

$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_ID' => $room_ID) );
$rows = $stm->fetchAll();

// echo row count here
$count = $stm->rowCount();
```

Comment: what does PDO have to do with this? a query is a query, regardless of what DB library you're using. The only differences are how you embed external data (e.g. that $_POST value).

Comment: @MarcB I'm not 100% sure how to echo out the row count number

Comment: Start with the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Cheers @MarcB, I've updated the code to show this.

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement`

Comment: `$count = $stm->fetchColumn()` will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total number of rows, use [fetchColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) function.

And one more correction, since you are using **JOIN** here so in the **ON clause**, you can't use the variable value, use column name only.

```
$room_ID = $_POST["room"];

$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    ts_room a
        INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
            ON a.id = b.room_ID
        INNER JOIN ts_request c
            ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1 and b.room_ID=:room_ID";

$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_ID' => $room_ID) );
$rows = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your query once:I have highlited the condition ehich you doing wrong this will be put in where clause .

```
  SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    ts_room a
            INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
                 // ON a.id = b.:room_ID
            INNER JOIN ts_request c
                ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
    WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1
```

I guess your code will be look like this:

$room_ID = $_POST["room"];

```
$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    ts_room a
        INNER JOIN ts_roompref b
            ON a.id = b.room_ID
        INNER JOIN ts_request c
            ON b.request_ID = c.roompref_ID
WHERE   c.day_ID = 1 AND c.period_ID = 1 and b.room_ID=:room_ID";

$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':room_ID' => $room_ID) );
$rows = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: How would I get the row count? Do I just echo $rows?